# Зависание при обращении к несуществующему элементу AngleSharp

Tags: c#, xamarin, anglesharp

Есть код

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Parser()
 {//
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        var documentleft = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(//сайт//);

        var CompareStatSquadLeft = documentleft.All.Where(m =>
        m.LocalName == "a" &&
        m.HasAttribute("class") &&
        m.GetAttribute("class").Contains("user-profile__data-link")
        ).ElementAt(0).TextContent.ToString(); // здесь зависает
  //
 }
```

Проблема в том. Что данный элемент "user-profile__data-link" на некоторых страницах отсутствует и вместо выброса какого либо исключения, не происходит ничего. Управление дальше, на следующую строку кода просто не передается (в дебаге проверил). По этой же причине не могу сделать проверку if !=null.

Как решить?

Comment: Раз вам нужен первый элемент, то может, вместо Where и ElementAt лучше использовать FirstOrDefault?

Comment: @Emigrant нет, опять зависает

Comment: Вряд ли оно зависает. Скорее всего, выбрасывается исключение (NullReferenceException) и где-то выше глотается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:
Сначала просто записываем

```
  var CompareStatSquadLeft = documentleft.All.FirstOrDefault(m =>
m.LocalName == "a" &&
m.HasAttribute("class") &&
m.GetAttribute("class").Contains("user-profile__data-link")
```

и только потом делаем проверку !=null и внутри ищем нужный элемент